# Understanding counters in CUDA profiler

Tags: cuda

I'm facing difficulty in understanding sm_cta counter in CUDA profiler. I'm launching 128 blocks and my launch bound configs are `__launch_bounds(192,8)` but profiler is showing 133 for particular run. I profiled app for several times but it is around 133 everytime. What this counter indicates? Using Tesla C2075, Linux 32bit.

Comment: which cuda version are you using?  what do you get if you use the sm_cta_launched counter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NVIDIA GPUs have Performance Monitor Units in multiple locations of the chip. On Fermi devices the sm_cta_launched signal is collected by the GPC monitor not the SM monitor. The Fermi GPC Performance Monitor is limited to observing 1 SM per GPC. The C2075 has 4 GPCs and 14 SMs. A C2075 could have a configuration of 2 GPCs with 4 SMs and 2 GPCs with 3 SMs. The CUDA profiler will collect the counter for 1 SM per GPC and multiply the result by the number of SMs in the GPC. The final value can be higher or lower than the expected value. For example:

```
GPC     SMs     Counter Value
0       4       8       32
1       4       8       32
2       3       11      33
3       3       12      36
---------------------------
                       133
```

In the document [Compute Command Line Profiler](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/Compute_Command_Line_Profiler_User_Guide.pdf) this information is specified under the countermodeaggregate option.

> countermodeaggregate
>
> If this option is selected then aggregate counter values will be
>   output. For a SM counter the counter value is the sum of the counter
>   values from all SMs. For l1*, tex*, sm_cta_launched,
>   uncached_global_load_transaction and global_store_transaction counters
>   the counter value is collected for 1 SM from each GPC and it is
>   extrapolated for all SMs. This option is supported only for CUDA
>   devices with compute capability 2.0 or higher.

A more accurate value can be achieved by using warps_launched which is collected per SM using the formula:

```
thread_blocks_launched = warps_launched
    / ((threadblocksizeX * threadblocksizeY * threadblocksizeZ) + WARP_SIZE - 1)
    / WARP_SIZE

    where WARP_SIZE is 32 on all current devices.
```

NOTE: This approach will not be correct for Dynamic Parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Some CUDA library functions are also implemented using kernels internally, so it is not surprising the total number of blocks executed is slightly higher than what you explicitly launched yourself.

Comment: How come it is slightly more? I'm launching 128 blocks and I have 14 SMs but still counters are showing that sm_Cta =133..

Comment: Which other CUDA functions are you calling? Some of them also launch blocks.

Comment: But 133 is far more than 8 isn't it? and i'm sure i'm not using any library that launches so many threads..

Comment: I believe the counter sm_cta may be counting the total number of blocks launched, not the number of blocks launched on sm0, so I think the answer given by @tera makes sense.  You may be calling some other function that is making the difference between 128 blocks in your app and 133 total.   I have profiled with sm_cta_launched on cuda5 and that is what I see.